# Aggregate points to polygons in QGIS

Tags: aggregate-points

Does anyone know if there is a tool to make polygons (perimeter) from a cluster of points but defining a certain distance using QGIS?

Like Aggregate points (cartography) using Arcmap

Comment: Have you seen this topic [Displaying multipoint features as polygon using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322739/displaying-multipoint-features-as-polygon-using-qgis/322803#322803)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the less complicated way is to make a convex hull:

```
vector > geoprocessing tools > convex hull
```

And then a buffer of the convex hull output with the distance required:

```
vector > geoprocessing tools > buffer
```