# Finding "Add Feature" Tab in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, toolbar

[image]I recently upgraded by QGIS from 2.18 to 3.4. Apart from a bunch of issues, I am not able to find the add feature tab. I want to create a set of polygons based on points.

Can someone help me with either letting me know what the issue is or a workaround?

Comment: @Taras my advanced digitizing toolbar is enable but I cannot see the add polygon feature.

Comment: @Taras I just added a screen capture of the issue

Answer (score 4):

The thing that you are looking for is emphasized in blue.

[image: result]

P.S. Just check slightly above the highlighted toolbar.

Comment: This is to add a point feature. I want to create geofences with existing points. I was able to do in QGIS 2.18, but not in this version.

Comment: Can you please collaborate your question? Because what you are requiring has nothing to do with what you are asking in this question. Do you want to create polygons out of points? Thus I can refer you to this thread [Displaying multipoint features as polygon using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322739/displaying-multipoint-features-as-polygon-using-qgis/322803#322803)