# Aggregate points inside polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, nearest-neighbor, count

I have a project that I am required to aggregate points inside polygons that have a common value.
Basically having QGIS to create a buffer around those points.

[image]

The dark green arrows have a unique value of 12, and I need to fit 6 of them inside a polygon.
The dark blue arrows have a unique value of 16, and I need to fit 4 of them inside a polygon.

The other arrows have other values but follow the same idea of the previous two.

I already used several tools: Concave hull, Attribute based clustering and other native tools from QGIS. None gave me the result I need.

From my understanding, I need a tool that checks the points that are in the neighborhood of other points (that share the same value) and then it creates a polygon around them (but never having more points than those I tell it).

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322739/displaying-multipoint-features-as-polygon-using-qgis

Answer (score 1):

Connect all points with a line to the `n` nearest points with the same attribute value, where `n` is the number of points you want to aggregate to a group. You can use different values for `n` for different attribute values (like based on your example n=6 for value=12).

Then create the convex hull of these lines, dissolve the result and convertt multipart to single part geometries. To do this, proceed as follows:

1. Use Geometry by expression with this expression:

   ```
    convex_hull( 
        with_variable (
            'no',
            case
            when value = 12 then 8  -- define here how many points you want to cluster together for each value
            when value = 8 then 6
            when value = 2 then 4
            end,
            collect_geometries (
                array_foreach (
                    with_variable(
                        'val',
                        value,
                        eval ('
                            overlay_nearest (
                                ''points'',  -- adapt the name of your points layer
                                $geometry,
                                filter:=value='  || @val  || ',
                                limit:=@no-1
                            )'
                        )
                    ),
                    make_line (
                        $geometry, 
                        @element
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
   ```
2. Apply `Menu Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Dissolve` to the result
3. Apply `Menu Vector > Geometry tools > Multipart to Singleparts` to the output.

*Result: Points with value 2 are grouped to groups of 4 , value 8 to groups of 6, value 12 to groups of 8:*
[image]

*Result after step 1 with geometry generator:*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that solution doesn't work.
Using it creates overlapped polygons :/

Comment: This solution works based on what kind of data you have. Structured as in my test case, it produces the correct result, but that might not be the case for your data. So providing sample data would be a good idea.