# Customized point cluster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, csv, clustering

I have a CSV table containing:

- date
- time
- species(birds)
- count(birds) and
- point coordinates.

I want to group the points by different bird species. I tried using a point cluster but it sums the count of birds respectively the number of points. I want to show how many different species there are.

Comment: The question is unclear to me: What do you mean by "group the points"? How should the result look like?

Comment: Have you seen this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322739/displaying-multipoint-features-as-polygon-using-qgis ?

Comment: This is how point cluster looks like:
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RID8K.jpg but "Point Cluster" counts and groups every single bird location. I want to show how many different species there are. And this is how attribute table looks like: [2]:https://i.imgur.com/X3MFgmQ.jpg

Comment: @NikolayYordanov please add these details into your original question